# $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable then $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(f^{-1}(\{x\})) > 0\}$ is countable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function on the $\sigma$-finite space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$. Show that the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(f^{-1}(\{x\})) > 0\}$ is countable.

My idea of approaching this was to use the fact that $X = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ and then either construct some sort of bijection between the $A_n$'s and our set, or show that if our set is uncountable then we cannot have $\sigma$-additivity. But I couldn't really figure out a way to formally follow through with these ideas.

Comment: Hint: $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(f^{-1}(\{x\})) > 0\}=\bigcup_n \{x\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(f^{-1}(\{x\})) > 1/n\}$.